# Test Accuracy (Image Classification) in Python

Tags: python, image, artificial-intelligence, classification

I already trained my dataset and have already plot it as well. Everything seems good but when I wanted to print the Test Accuracy

`print('\nTest accuracy:', acc)`

and the output was like this

`Test accuracy: [0.7384201, 0.8907454, 0.9277824, 0.9450478, 0.9409635, 0.9640769, 0.97057456, 0.9810638, 0.9780934, 0.980414, 0.9876543, 0.9918314, 0.9961014, 0.9967511, 0.9906247]`

I dont understand bcs what I expected was `Test accuracy: 0.8802` (for example)

Here's my [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YVXF6aEMyZrPhMaI0W44XxlhivqCaV20), full code

Comment: I can't see the notebook: `Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.

Error loading https://apis.google.com/js/client.js
https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=1YVXF6aEMyZrPhMaI0W44XxlhivqCaV20&authuser=0`

Comment: sorry my bad would u like to take a look again I just updated

Answer (score 0):

literally i just have to do this `print(np.sum(acc)/len(acc))` instead